# Magento FPC EE 1.14: Flush single block from observer / helper

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, redis, magento-1.14

I have custom Magento Block (Featured Products) on HomePage. I'm also using FPC (+ Cm_Redis). I've made HolePunch to be independent from other parts of App.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <placeholders>
        <company_home_page_featured_products>
            <block>package/package_product_list_simple</block>
            <placeholder>CMP_HOME_PAGE_FEATURED_PRODUCTS</placeholder>
            <container>Company_Package_Model_Container_Package_Product_List_Simple</container>
            <cache_lifetime>86400</cache_lifetime>
        </company_home_page_featured_products>
    </placeholders>
</config>
```

The problem is that some products can change using API, other from Backend and I'd like to be able to refresh (flush) this block from Observer or just in Helper.

Could you help me how to perform this cache flush? I tried

```
Enterprise_PageCache_Model_cache::getCacheInstance()->remove('CMP_HOME_PAGE_FEATURED_PRODUCTS');
```

... but without success.

Answer (score 0):

try to use 
`Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cache::getCacheInstance()->clean('CMP_HOME_PAGE_FEATURED_PRODUCTS');`
and write a [processor](http://www.techytalk.info/magento-enterprise-edition-full-page-cache-your-own-controller-action/)